# Why keyup works but keydown does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, keydown, keyup

I have an input type="number" where the min value is 1, the max is 10. I want to prevent inputting a value greater or less than max and min, so I use this script:

```js
$('input[name=inputModal1]').keyup(function(){
if($(this).val()>10){
  $(this).val(10);
}else if($(this).val()<1){
  $(this).val(1);}
});
$('input[name=inputModal2]').keydown(function(){
if($(this).val()>10){
  $(this).val(10);
}else if($(this).val()<1){
  $(this).val(1);}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="inputModal1" min="1" max="10" value="1">
<input type="number" name="inputModal2" min="1" max="10" value="1">
```

In this kind the script works, but I want to use `keydown`, it prevents entering more or less than the maximum and minimum value, but `keyup` gives more or less typing if the user presses and holds the button. What could be the reason that `keydown` is not working? I can remove the value, make it more than 10, etc.

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is to do with the order of events. `keydown` fires on the element **before** the value has been set. Therefore `$(this).val()` is `''` when the event fires, which confuses your logic.

To fix this issue, and improve the behaviour, use the `input` event instead. This works as you require, and also fires when the user adds content to the element in any way - pasting via the mouse for example.

In addition you can use `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` to make your logic more succinct. Try this:

```js
$('input[name=inputModal]').on('input', function() {
  $(this).val((i, v) => Math.max(Math.min(this.value, 10), 0));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="inputModal" min="1" max="10">
```